# Passport-discord not calling serialiseUser nor deserialiseUser

Tags: node.js, nestjs, passport.js

I am trying to setup discord oauth in nestjs using passport-discord.

```
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport'
import { Strategy, VerifyCallback } from '@oauth-everything/passport-discord'
import { config } from 'dotenv'
import { DiscordProfile } from 'src/types'
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common'
import { UsersService } from 'src/users/users.service'
config()

@Injectable()
export class DiscordStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'discord') {
  constructor(private readonly _usersService: UsersService) {
    super({
      clientID: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: process.env.DISCORD_CALLBACK_URL,
      scope: process.env.DISCORD_SCOPES.split(' '),
      successRedirect: 'http://localhost:8000/dashboard',
    })
  }
  async validate(
    _accessToken: string,
    _refreshToken: string,
    profile: DiscordProfile,
    done: VerifyCallback
  ) {
    try {
      const user = await this._usersService.findByDiscordId(profile.id)
      console.log('FROM STRAEGY', user)
      if (!user) {
        const createdUser = await this._usersService.createDiscordUser({
          discordId: profile.id,
          email: profile.email,
          discordUsername: profile.username,
        })

        done(null, createdUser)
      }
      done(null, user)
    } catch (e) {
      done(e, null)
    }
  }
}
```

This is how my Strategy looks

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { PassportSerializer } from '@nestjs/passport'
import { User } from '@prisma/client'
import { UsersService } from '../users/users.service'

@Injectable()
export class UserSerializer extends PassportSerializer {
  constructor(private readonly _userService: UsersService) {
    super()
  }

  serializeUser(user: User, done: Function) {
    console.log('SERIALISED USER ', user)
    done(null, user)
  }

  async deserializeUser(userRef: User, done: Function) {
    console.log('DESERIALIZED USER')
    const user = await this._userService.findByEmail(userRef.email)

    delete user.password
    if (!user) {
      return done(`Could not deserialize user: user with ${userRef.email} could not be found`, null)
    }

    done(null, user)
  }
}
```

this is how my `Serialiser` looks

```
@Module({
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    PrismaService,
    UsersService,
    LocalStrategy,
    UserSerializer,
    DiscordStrategy,
  ],
})
```

`AuthModule`

Now for some reason as you can see I am using LocalStrategy too which calls both of these methods but passport-discord doesnt hence request.user is not populated in requests whereas in the callback request it is defined and session is created even the user is stored in database but when trying to fetch user in other requests it doesnt seem to exist the cookie is being passed just fine too

Comment: I`m facing the same issue and my code looks very similar. Did you figured out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try to add authenticate function in your DiscordStrategy class then call passport.authenticate('discord') on the route where you handle discord login

```
export class DiscordStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'discord') {
...
authenticate() {
    super.authenticate((err, user, info) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err
      }
      if (!user) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException()
      }
      req.user = user
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The request.user object is not populated in subsequent requests after the authentication callback. You need to configure session support in your Nest.js application.
Assuming your dependencies are installed:

```
 npm install express-session
 npm install passport
```

Import and configure the express-session middleware in your main application file (e.g., main.ts or app.module.ts):

```
import session from 'express-session';

// ...

 app.use(
  session({
  secret: 'your-secret-key',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
 }),
);
```

Import and configure the passport module in your main application file:

```
import passport from 'passport';

// ...

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Update your UserSerializer class to serialize and deserialize the user correctly:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportSerializer } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { User } from '@prisma/client';
import { UsersService } from '../users/users.service';

@Injectable()
export class UserSerializer extends PassportSerializer 
{
  constructor(private readonly _userService: UsersService) 
{
  super();
}

serializeUser(user: User, done: Function) 
{
 console.log('SERIALIZED USER', user);
 done(null, user.id);
}

async deserializeUser(userId: string, done: Function) 
{
  console.log('DESERIALIZED USER');
  const user = await this._userService.findById(userId);

if (!user) 
{
  return done(
    `Could not deserialize user: user with id ${userId} could not be 
found`,
    null,
  );
 }

 done(null, user);
 }
}
```

Make sure to import and use the UserSerializer in your application module (e.g., AuthModule):

```
import { UserSerializer } from './user.serializer';

// ...

@Module({
// ...
  providers: 
  [
    // ...
    UserSerializer,
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

The request.user object should be populated and accessible in subsequent requests after the authentication callback. Ensure that you have configured and enabled session support for Passport in your application to maintain user state across requests.

Answer (score 0):

Can you follow my approach?

1. Ensure that you have session support configured in your Nest app by installing the **express-session** package.
2. Import and configure the **express-session** middleware in your main application file (**main.ts** or **app.module.ts**).

```
import session from 'express-session';

// ...

app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'your-secret-key',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  }),
);
```

3. Import and configure the **passport** middleware in your main application file.

```
import session from 'express-session';

// ...

app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'your-secret-key',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  }),
);
```

4. Update your **UserSerializer** class to correctly serialize and deserialize the user.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportSerializer } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { User } from '@prisma/client';
import { UsersService } from '../users/users.service';

@Injectable()
export class UserSerializer extends PassportSerializer {
  constructor(private readonly _userService: UsersService) {
    super();
  }

  serializeUser(user: User, done: Function) {
    console.log('SERIALIZED USER', user);
    done(null, user.id);
  }

  async deserializeUser(userId: string, done: Function) {
    console.log('DESERIALIZED USER');
    const user = await this._userService.findById(userId);

    if (!user) {
      return done(
        `Could not deserialize user: user with id ${userId} could not be found`,
        null,
      );
    }

    done(null, user);
  }
}
```

5. Make sure to import and use the **UserSerializer** in your application module (e.g., **AuthModule**).

```
import { UserSerializer } from './user.serializer';

// ...

@Module({
  // ...
  providers: [
    // ...
    UserSerializer,
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Then can you check again if the **request.user** object should be populated and accessible in subsequent requests after the authentication callback.

Hope this answer would give you a hint though it doesn't resolve your issue completely.